# How can I mutate a parameter that was passed by move?

Tags: rust

My understanding is if I have a function like:

```
fn f(x: Vec<u32>) -> (some result)
```

`f` takes ownership of `x`. `f` is now responsible for `x`'s destruction.

If this is the case, can I mutate `x`, and if so how? To get a mutable iterator to `x` requires a `&mut`, which I don't have.

It seems reasonable that I should be able to mutate a variable I now have ownership over without any ill effects I'm just not sure how. The calling function has relinquished ownership of `x` to `f`, so it shouldn't care what happens to it.

Perhaps I could change the type `f` to `f(x: &mut Vec<u32>)`, but I don't really want to do that for a variety of reasons, for example it prevents chaining functions in a natural way like `f(g(x))`, and also if my "(some result)" is something other than a `Vec<u32>` (like a type that contains a `Vec<u32>`) then I'll have to split the function into two and ensure the caller does what they're supposed to do.

Comment: You don't even have to change the function declaration. You can just add `let mut x = x;` at the beginning. As you understood, the fonction took ownership of the variable, it owns it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the `x` argument to be mutable: `mut x: Whatever`

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec![];
    mutate(x);
}

fn mutate(mut x: Vec<u32>) {
    x.push(1);
}
```

Comment: Oh I'm silly I just wrote `x : mut Vec<u32>` instead and it didn't compile. That does the job perfectly. Only been using Rust for a few weeks (but enjoying it). Thanks! Will accept your answer after the minimum time expires.

Answer (score 2):

You could shadow `x`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = vec![];
    mutate(x);
}

fn mutate(x: Vec<u32>) {
    let mut x = x;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But why ? Isn't that just one additional line that can be easily avoided?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I didn't said "must", style preference I guess. I found it's better than `mut x: Vec<u32>`. This "hide" the fact we are doing terrible side effect.